# Calculating Angle Between Two Circles With Same Center Point - Mercury Retrogrades

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, angle

I want to calculate the angle between points on two circles with the same center point. Each point is a planet in its orbit. I have the degrees of each point in the circle. What I want to know is how to calculate the angle between the two. I'm using this to calculate the retrogrades of Mercury, and have been working on this project for about three weeks. Maybe you know a better way to do it?

```
Mercury: 329
Earth  : 77
```

Where the value for Mercury and Earth are in degrees.

I'm learning the math as I go, so if you could explain things that would be great!

I have the ratio of Mercury's orbit to Earth. This changes based on the date.

```
Mercury: 0.431094585293355

Earth: 0.985210404350114
```

Try to calculate the angle between the gray dot and the blue dot, from the perspective of the black dot. Angle ME When the numbers are given in degrees.

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of 329 and 77 ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/5PShzdh do you want gamma or delta in this image?  or something else?

Comment: @DanUznanski That looks like what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm trying to write a program that calculates the angle, so I need the formula to make it happen. Maybe the formula for both, but what is the difference?

Comment: @Dan Uznanski You should post your graphics as an answer as I have done.

Comment: @JeanMarie 329 is the angle in degrees going around the sun. From a heliocentric orbit, the position on the circle each planet is at.

Comment: @JeanMarie it's not an answer though it's a clarifying question

Comment: @Dan Uznanski IAnother way is to include your graphics into the text of the OP (after due grant of permission...). It would contribute to dialog at least by fixing notations...

Comment: I just see your graphics. If you want to work with the real elliptic (instead of roughly circularized) orbit, it is much more complicated...

Comment: @JeanMarie I've already calculated the eccentric orbit. It is included in the degrees shown for Mercury.

Comment: Therefore, you no longer consider concentric "circles" as indicated in your title ?

Comment: HI, with the ratio of Mercury to Earths Orbit, I would think it would be simple to figure out how to calculate the angle? My math skills are not great, I'm no professor. Two circles is close enough for what I'm trying to calculate. I do however know its less than perfect. You are likely a genius compared to my abilities. But I am trying. @JeanMarie

Comment: Genius! Certainly not. I have just more practise in geometry. [I got only progressively confidence into myself, being convinced when I was young to be inferior to most of my fellows]. Besides: is my formula (2) understandable (you can check it on a hand calculator) ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this figure featuring the idealized (!) circular and concentric orbits of the Earth (E) and Mercury (M).

[image]

Let us apply to triangle $ESM_1$ the "sine rule" stating that  the sines of angles are in the same ratio as the lengths of opposite sides, giving, with Astronomical Units:

$$\frac{\sin a}{SM_1}=\frac{\sin (\pi-(a+b))}{SE} \ \iff \ \frac{\sin a}{0.387}=\frac{\sin (a+b)}{1} \tag{1}$$

(we have used the fact that the sum of angles in a triangle is $\pi$ radians)

$b$ can be extracted from (1) in the following way:

$$b=\sin^{-1}\left(\tfrac{1}{0.387} \sin a\right)-a \ \ \ \ \ \text{(a and b in radians)}\tag{2}$$

which become, for angles defined in degrees:

$$b=\tfrac{180}{\pi}\sin^{-1}\left(\tfrac{1}{0.387} \sin a \tfrac{\pi}{180}\right)-a \tfrac{\pi}{180}\tag{2'}$$

Is it this kind of formula you are looking for ($a$ being the angle observed on your instrument), from which you deduce the relative angle $b$ ?

Formula (2) is valid for point $M_1$ ; it must be adapted to compute the angle associated with the other possible position $M_2$ for the same observation angle $a$. Do you see how ?

Comment: I was using a heliocentric positioning based upon the sun; and the degrees of each planet around the sun. Then figure out the angle between the two planets.

Comment: By "angle between the two planets $E,M$ (and the Sun ?)" do you mean angle ESM ? Are you conscious that you cannot retrieve a single angle but two possible angles ? The figure I have just made with a little Matlab program is intended to establish a dialog because **your text isn't clear**.  Please say first if you understand this figure or if it is unrelated. Unless, please, draw your own diagram.

Comment: Thank you. As I have a limited understanding of what I'm doing, it is difficult. I don't know the names of what everything is called. The diagram by Dan Uznanski made sense to me to determine what I want to know. Please see his diagram for what I want. I think I want the delta angle, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who try taking on projects like this, I recommend two books by Montenbruck. Practical Ephemeris Calculations, and Astronomy on the Personal Computer. There have been people make programs that do all this, save yourself the hassle, and use what others have made. It is out there.

I found a solution in what someone else made.